# Resizing collapsed legend item in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

I would like to resize an item which seems way too small in my legend (see picture below)
[image: Legend to resize]

I would like to resize it so it looks like this:

[image: Legend I would like]

I don't understand why it scales like this when I put it as a legend.

Comment: There are lot of Legend item properties that can be changed that might affect how it looks, including spacing and position and size, reference point.   As for nesting the symbols that probably requires making a graphic for your legend instead of using the Add Legend button.

Comment: Making a graphic seems too complicated for me actually. I'll try switching between different settings, but changing sizex make no differences actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are experiencing [this bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34166) which is present in QGIS 3.10. It has been fixed in later versions however my understanding is that the fix was not suitable to be backported to 3.10.
If that is the version you are using you should upgrade to a more recent release if possible.

Comment: I was on QGIS "Bucuresti" (3.12.3) but the update in 3.16 fully solved my problem. Thank you very much !

Comment: No worries, glad your problem is solved.